# How to use Jasmine to test Angular App's Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm practicing Angular and automated testing.

I made a simple app to tell the user the strength of their password. Originally everything was within the PasswordController and used $scope. Then I moved the logic into a service. The controller and service are currently this:

```
myApp.controller("PasswordController", function ($scope, PasswordService) {

  $scope.users = PasswordService.list();

  $scope.saveUser = function () {
    PasswordService.save($scope.newUser);
    $scope.newUser = {};
  }

  $scope.delete = function (id) {
    PasswordService.delete(id);
    if($scope.newUser.id == id){
      $scope.newUser = {};
    }
  }

  $scope.edit = function(id) {
    $scope.newUser = angular.copy(PasswordService.get(id));
  }
});

myApp.service('PasswordService', function() {

  //user with unique id
  var uid = 1;

  //user array
  var users = [
    {
      id: 0,
      'name': 'a_test_name',
      'password': 'a_test_pw',
      'pwStrength': 'medium'
    }
  ];

  this.save = function(user) {
    if (user.id == null) {
      user.id = uid++;
      this.grade(user);
      users.push(user);
    }
    else {
      for (i in users) {
        if (users[i].id == user.id) {
          users[i] = user;
          this.grade(user);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  this.get = function(id) {
    for (i in users) {
      if (users[i].id == id) {
        return users[i];
      }
    }
  }

  this.delete = function(id) {
    for (i in users) {
      if (users[i].id == id) {
        users.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  this.list = function () {
    return users;
  }

  this.grade = function(user) { 
    var size = user.password.length;
    if (size > 8) {
      user.pwStrength = "strong";
    }
    else if (size > 3) {
      user.pwStrength = "medium";
    }
    else {
      user.pwStrength = "weak";
    }
  }
});
```

My test cases had all been working when everything was in the PasswordController but I can't figure out how to set up the test cases to use the service. This is the test code without modifications: (so some of the variable names don't quite line up)

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var $controller;
  var $scope;
  var controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe("$scope.grade", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      $scope = {};
      controller = $controller("PasswordController", { $scope: $scope });
    });

    it("method should exist", function() {
      expect($scope.grade).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });

    it('strength to "medium" if the password length is >8 chars && <3 chars', function() {
      $scope.password = 'between';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('medium');
    });

    it('sets the strength to "weak" if the password length <3 chars', function() {
      $scope.password = 'a';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('weak');
    });
  });
});
```

I can't figure out how I'd convert the test cases to use the PasswordService. I've tried to inject the PasswordService into the controller and tried to use spyOn to mock the service and use it that way but so far no luck.

```
  beforeEach(module('myApp', function ($provide) {
    PasswordService = jasmine.createSpyObj("PasswordService", ["save" ...]);

controller = $controller("PasswordController", { $scope: $scope, PasswordSerice: PasswordService });
```

Any hints of links to tutorials are appreciated. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Since you separate the controller and the service (what was probably a good thing), now it also makes sense to separate the tests.

You should create one test for the controller. The test will aim for the methods inside the controller only (save, delete and edit).

And then you create another test for the service which will cover the methods inside the service.

I will create an example example for both scenarios to help you out:

```
describe('PasswordController Specification', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var myPasswordController;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope){
    myPasswordController= _$controller_('PasswordController', {
         $scope: $rootScope.$new();
    });
  }));

  it("Should save the user", inject(function(PasswordService) {
    //setup
    var myFakeUser = {id: 1, name: 'whatever'};
    myPasswordController.newUser = myFakeUser;

    /*
    Here I am spying the save method. This is necessary to check if it was 
    called. It will actually replace the original implementation with a 
    mocked empty function. And this is right because the controller  
    shouldn't if the service is doing what is supposed to. This is up for 
    the service test.
    */
    spyOn(PasswordService, 'save');

    //action
    myPasswordController.saveUser(myMockedUser);

    //assertion
    expect(PasswordService.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(myPasswordController.newUser).toBe({});
  }));
});
```

And the service test:

```
describe('PasswordService Specification', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var myPasswordService;

  beforeEach(inject(function(PasswordService){
    myPasswordService = PasswordService;
  }));

  it("Should save new user", inject(function() {
    //setup
    var numberOfUsers= myPasswordService.list().length;
    var newUser = {
        'name': 'a_test_name',
        'password': 'a_test_pw',
        'pwStrength': 'medium'
    }
    /*
    Here I am spying the grade method. This is necessary to check if it was 
    called. It will actually replace the original implementation with a 
    mocked empty function. And this is right because we are only concerned
    about the save method now.
    */
    spyOn(myPasswordService, 'grade');

    //action
    myPasswordService.save(newUser);

    //assertion
    expect(myPasswordService.grade).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(myPasswordService.list().length).toBe(numberOfUsers + 1);
  }));
});
```

There are other things that you could test but I hope this gives you an insight to start your work

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much! That was incredibly helpful.

Comment: In the service test line:
  beforeEach(inject(function(myPasswordService){
    myPasswordService = myPasswordService;
  }));
should we be passing PasswordService into the function since that is the name of the service? And then set myPasswordService = PasswordService (as far as your example goes)?

Comment: There's no right answer for that. You could have that there if you will be using the PasswordService in many "it" blocks. It would be just a way of reducing lines of code. You just need to analyse if your code will be more organized or not.

Comment: I guess I'm confused how the service 'PasswordService' is linked to the service test then? How can we use .save or .grade on myPassWordService? Where was Password service imported or included?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just now understood what you're talking. You're absolutely right and it was a mistype. I will fix it on the example.